# Contact Builder attributes not showing up

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

Trying to make Syncronised Data Extension attributes to be available for MobileConnect group in Contact Builder / Data Designer.

Despite linking the Account_Salesforce syncronised data extension to the MobileConnect Demographics table, the list of available attributes is not showing up in MobileConnect contact Attribute list.

Is there a step I'm missing here? There wasn't anything extra in documentation.

The only thing I can think of is the fact that on MobileConnect Demographics we have 18-digit contact ID field and on Account_Salesforce we have 15-digit contact ID, which are used to link these.

[image: 18digit-vs-15digit][image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Thats strange. I thought that when SF exports it's ID it adds an extra 3 digits to it to make it 18?

Comment: Could you expand a bit more where you want to use this data? Is it for creating segments or?

If you are pulling SFIDs in via Marketing Cloud Connect (which should be the way), the ID should ALWAYS be 18 digits.

Comment: Hi @Data_Kid - I apologize, you were right. Checked the Account_Salesforece syncronised data extensiona and the PersonContactID is indeed 18 digits. This then rules out the possibility of the ID's not matching.

Comment: Hi @Kenneth Wagner - Idea is to use Salesforce attributes in MobileConnect, so we could use SF fields in SMS sendings, for personalization. I'm adding a second picture where these attributes are missing. The attribute tab list, basically. There is no Account_Salesforce tab with SF attributes. I wonder if it could be because the Contact Key for this contact is a custom ID? Even though the "Salesforce ID" is also shown under MobileConnect Data

Comment: Hi Atheri - you don't have access to that information at send time, I'll try and elaborate a bit an post relevant answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall, the challenge is that you only have access to data that is stored in the [mobile demographics table](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/contacts/demographics_table/), and not linked data sets to my knowledge.

If you want to  include personalization, this is done using ampscript, which numerous examples can be found in the links below. Conceptually, you use the mobile number at send time, to reference an attribute value (e.g. SFID) which you've created on the demograhics table, and then you use that value to reference your personalization strings.

There are numerous resources that deal with personalization in Mobile Connect:
[Personalization in Mobile Connect SMS called within Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75986/personalization-in-mobile-connect-sms-called-within-journey-builder)
[MobileConnect Send Time Variables?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169146/mobileconnect-send-time-variables) 
[Outbound SMS referencing event source data?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171255/outbound-sms-referencing-event-source-data)

```
%%[
VAR @ContactRows, @ContactRow, @RowCount, @ContactKey

SET @ContactKey = AttributeValue("Salesforce_ID")
SET @ContactRows = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","PersonContactId", @contactKey)
SET @RowCount = RowCount(@ContactRows)

IF @RowCount > 0 then

    /* Write out your values here */

ENDIF
]%%
Reference values here using %%=v(@YourValue)=%%
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60540/discussion-on-answer-by-kenneth-wagner-contact-builder-attributes-not-showing-up).

Comment: Atheri - did it solve everything? Or are more things needed? (and thanks for moving it to chat Adrian)

Comment: Hi KennethWagner, I tried doing SET @ContactKey = AttributeValue("Salesforce_ID") however It doesnt return any value. I've already added this attribute in my MobileConnect Demographics